# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 15525000 into shape (260,260) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, reshape

I have a problem about reshaping dataframe for implementing CNN.

My dataframe shape : `train.shape` -> (230, 67502).

Then I wrote a code shown below.

```
Y_train = train["Label"]
X_train = train.drop(labels = ["Label"],axis = 1)
```

When I run this code below for plotting some images by `iloc`, It throws an error

```
img = X_train.iloc[0].to_numpy()
img = np.pad(img, (0, (67600-img.shape[0])), 'constant').reshape((260, 260))
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.title(train.iloc[0,0])
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Then I normalize X_train

```
X_train = X_train / 255.0
print("x_train shape: ",X_train.shape)
```

When I reshape X_train , it throws an error

```
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1, 260, 260)
print("x_train shape: ",X_train.shape)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 15525000 into shape (260,260)
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: 260*260 doesn't equal 67500, so you would need to pad you array before you can reshape it.

Comment: @Dan How can I do pad process?

Comment: @Ben.T Is it possible to share some codes related with it?

Comment: @Ben.T How can I add more values by using np.pad in the dataframe?

Comment: @TonyBrand try `img = np.pad(img, (0, (67600-img.shape[0])), 'constant').reshape((260, 260))`?

Comment: @Ben.T How can I do reshape again after normalization ? Is it right ? X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,260,260,1)

Comment: @TonyBrand I don't understand where your normalization thing comes in, but if you want to pad the whole X_train try `np.pad(X_train, ((0,0), (0, (67600-X_train.shape[1]))), 'constant')` and maybe follow by a `.reshape(-1, 260, 260)`, depending on how you build your CNN

Comment: @Ben.T I edited my post. Can you check it if you don't mind?

Comment: @Ben.T Can I use this code , can't I?  np.pad(X_train, ((0,0), (0, (67600-X_train.shape[1]))), 'constant').reshape(-1, 260, 260)

Comment: @TonyBrand yes it should work, don't forget to assign the result back to X_train, or to whatever other varaible name you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
X_train = np.pad(X_train, ((0,0), (0, (67600-X_train.shape[1]))), 'constant').reshape(-1, 260, 260)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `260*260` is `67600` and not `67500`. So you can't cast your array into those dimensions.

To actually cast it into those dimensions you would need to pad or normalize the source image arrays. For example, check the Keras [`pad_sequences`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences) functionality documentation on dealing with this kind of issues.

Comment: which way do I follow to get 67500 by implementing reshape process.

Comment: Square root of 67500 is not an integer, so you would need to pad / normalize your array somehow.

Comment: How can I do pad or normalize it? Before reshape I wrote this code for normalization (X_train = X_train / 255.0)

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you need a `260 * 260` image? As `67500 == 270 * 250`, you can try that and see how it looks!
Otherwise you would need to `PAD` - how exactly would depend upon your image.

But, one of the simplest might be to add `100` more `0's` at the end to make it `67600` - hence `260 * 260`

Comment: Here is my dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/quangqiyana/human-gender-identity. I try (250,270,1) and it its show 3 visuals in the image. To get 67500, Which numbers should I use for reshape?